# why i keep getting 'str' object is not callable when i use plt.title() and if i use plt.title = "mytitle", the title is not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code i wrote

```
#import the necessary modules
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#initialize the two empty lists and set it as y and y2
y = []
y2 = []

#iterate through 1-10 for the value of x
for x in range(1, 11):
        #store the equation into two lists
        y += [x ** 2 + 3 - math.log(x)]
        y2 += [x ** 2 + 3 + math.log(x)]

#plot y and add the lable
plt.plot(range(1, 11), y, label = 'subtracting log(x)')

#plot y2 and add the lable, also, turn the color into red
plt.plot(range(1, 11), y2 ,color = 'red', label = 'adding log(x)')

#set the lable of x and y axis
plt.xlabel = 'x-axis'
plt.ylabel = 'y-axis'

plt.title("Plot of y = x^2 + 3 - log(x) and y = x^2 + 3 + log(x)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and i keep getting this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/8q/q_5rzwtd5qx5mpvf4r9v10_40000gn/T/ipykernel_59793/986723238.py in <module>
     23 plt.ylabel = 'y-axis'
     24 
---> 25 plt.title("Plot of y = x^2 + 3 - log(x) and y = x^2 + 3 + log(x)")
     26 plt.legend()
     27 plt.show()

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

if i use plt.title = "Plot of y = x^2 + 3 - log(x) and y = x^2 + 3 + log(x)", it ran sucessfully, but the title is missing

i keep getting

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: If you assign `plt.title = "some string"`, then of course you will get that error if you try to call `plt.title()`, because it is not a function anymore...

Comment: But the posted code does not have the `plt.title = "some string"` assignment, so I don't see how that code would produce that error.

Comment: Are you running your code in a Jupyter notebook or some environment in which the memory may not get cleared? The code you posted is correct, but if you overwrite the function `plt.title` and set it to a string, it will remain a string even if you call `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` a second time so you need to either rerun the script or use `import importlib
importlib.reload(plt)`

Comment: ok i reloaded the jupyter notebook and it is working now, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Other issue: according the @JohnGordon answer, the correct is `plt.xlabel('x-axis')` and `plt.ylabel('y-axis')`